# have no light on my three.js scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, light

i have a problem. 
i have wrote some code on three.js, it consists of scene, 2 objects, renderer and camera. but when i added the light i didnt see the it!
i tried some options..but nothing helped me
my code there - http://codepen.io/usf/pen/LaDwh

```
var light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xff0000);
light.position.set( 0, 0, 50 );

var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff);
pointLight.position.set( 0, 0, 50 );

scene.add(light);
scene.add(pointLight);

//code
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

i dont know, what caused that problem :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`MeshBasicMaterial` does not respond to lights. Change your material to `MeshPhongMaterial`, for example.

Comment: I spent hours looking for this ... thank you