# lightMap / specularMap / shading with meshBasicMaterial

Tags: three.js

I'm currently working on something along the lines of a plugin for another program to add 3D capability to it, so I'm trying to put all the functionality i can from three.js into it, with  the added goal of this being a good way to learn all the functionality of three.js firsthand.

I'm running into an issue now as i implement textures and materials that with mesh basic material, setting some things which the documentation on the main threejs.org site shows are features, doesn't actually do anything.

when i set a texture for either specularmap or lightmap nothing is actually showing up. Im pretty sure its not a mistake im making because setting the texture of the map works, but trying to set this same texture for the specularMap or lightMap is doing nothing. Does a regular texture work for these, or do i have to do something different?

I'd also like to know what the shading property does for mesh basic, because as far as i can see setting it to smoothshading/flatshading/noshading is doing nothing aswell.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490619/have-no-light-on-my-three-js-scene

Comment: I have a light in my scene, and im aware it doesn't respond to lights, so i'm confused as to why it has the shading setting at all. that also doesn't explain why light maps aren't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MeshBasicMaterial` does not respond to lights. Change your material to `MeshLamberMaterial`  or `MeshPhongMaterial`, for example.

For `MeshBasicMaterial` and `MeshLambertMaterial`, the `specularMap` is used only to modulate the reflection when an environment map is used.

For any material, lightmaps require a second set of UVs. `geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ]` contains the usual set of UVs; for a lightmap, you need to add `geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 1 ]`, a second set of UVs.

For `MeshBasicMaterial`, the `shading` property only applies when an environment map is used. `SmoothShading` will yield smooth reflections; `FlatShading` will yield faceted reflections.

three.js r.66

Comment: Thank you, that was incredibly helpful!